# Структура с битовыми полями

Tags: c++

Использую структуру такого типа:

```
struct S
{
    T1 f1 : 1;
    T2 f2 : 3;
    T3 f3 : 4;
};
```

Где `T1` - `bool` (или `int`), а `T2` и `T3` - созданные ранее перечисления (`enum`). Количество элементов в `T2` - 8, а в `T3` - чуть меньше 16. Как я понимаю, структура должна занимать в памяти ровно 8 бит (1 + 3 + 4). На деле она занимает 8 байт (`cout<<sizeof(S);` выдает 8). Когда сохраняю структуру в файл, например:

```
S str;
fout.write((char*)&str, 1);
```

в файл записывается байт, значение которого определяется толко полем `f1`. Хотелось бы сохранять всю структуру одним байтом. Может быть лучше мне для этого использовать константы типа `char`. `a1 = 0x00, a2 = 0x80` - вместо первого поля, `b1 = 0x00, ..., b8 = 0x70` - вместо второго, и `с1 = 0x00, ..., c16 = 0x0F` - вместо третьего, а потом объединять их **побитовым или**( | ).

Comment: Вы реально думаете что bool = 1 бит? Не говорю ничего уже об enum

Comment: Нет, я не думаю, что bool = 1 бит, но, если я пишу "bool b : 1;" в структуре, я думаю, что программа должна выделять для его хранения 1 бит (без учета выравнивания). Или я не прав?

Comment: сорри, не обратил внимания (по плюсам не знаю)

Comment: Кстати, как выделить код в вопросе? 4-мя пробелами, как написано, вроде выделил, но что-то не видно.

Comment: код  010101 выделять

Comment: Где здесь кресты?! Это обычные Си. Правильной дорогой идете, так и надо. А если сомнения одолеют, вставьте compile-time проверку sizeof struct

Comment: "Где здесь кресты?!" В смысле С++? Так это не вся программа.

Comment: Спасибо. Только еще нужно было поменять порядок полей на обратный, чтобы структура сохранялась как надо. Если я не ошибаюсь, это связано с тем, что Windows применяет little-endian (поправьте, если ошибаюсь). Но почему перечисление всегда занимает 4 байта(как int?)? Можно ли это изменить?

Comment: Неа, это крестопроблемы. Поправят только в новом стандарте.

> The underlying type of an enumeration is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@iov_94](/users/5811/iov_94)](/users/5811/iov_94), попробуйте все поля структуры объявить как char. Кстати, при записи в файл лучше явно передавать размер структуры, а не надеяться что ее размер окажется равен именно данному числовому значению:

```
fout.write((char*)&str, sizeof(S));
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, такая структура будет занимать 3-4 байта. Все происходит из за выравнивания данных. Компилятор не знает, что Вы хотите их хранить в одном байте, и расставляет так, как ему кажется проще, быстрее. В результате каждое поле попадает в отдельный байт, плюс ещё один байт в конце для выравнивания (на многих платформах доступ к адресам кратным 4 значительно быстрее, чем к нечетным адресам).
Но компилятор можно попросить расставить поплотнее данные. Для этого читаем к примеру [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142662/) статью.

Comment: Даже когда использую #pragma pack(push, 1) перед структурой (ну и #pragma pack(pop) после нее), размер структуры становится 5 байт. Конечно не 8 как было, но нужно 1. По-моему, это из-за того что T2 и T3 - перечисления. Если T1, T2, T3 делаю char, то размер структуры становится как раз 1. Но как бы теряется смысл этих полей. Их можно теперь задавать какими-то абстрактными числами.

Comment: @iov_94, а какой смысл указывать тип битовых полей?;) Если важен размер, используйте char, если размер не важен, а важен тип - вообще не используйте битовые поля.

Comment: А можно ли поля использовать в классе, а не в структуре? Изменится ли при этом размер типа(класс не производный, без виртуальных функций, т.к. это мне вообще не нужно)? В конструкторе класса аргументы указать нужного типа, а хранить все как char. Можно ли такой конструктор сделать для структуры, а не для класса?

Comment: Конструктор для структуры? Никто не мешает. Синтаксис прежний.
Битовые поля в классе? Да сколько угодно. Размер класса скорее всего не будет отличаться от подобной себе структуры.
Но спросите, а почему же все таки 5 байт получилось? а все потому, что Вам никто не обещал, что Ваши типы влезут в заданные Вами размеры. Вообще то лучше сделать себе один int (а лучше выбрать платформенно независимый тип) и ручками сохранить в правильном, идеальном порядке.

Comment: Большое спасибо, KoVadim, за Ваши ответы. Мне они во многом помогли. Но бОльшую пользу мне все-таки принес ответ insolor. К несчастью, этот ответ был приведен в виде комментария, поэтому я не могу его отметить как правильный. Можно ли отметить комментарий как правильный ответ? Если нет, просьба к insolor: сделайте свой комментарий (самый первый) ответом.